# Determining whether $(\frac32,\frac52)$ is a critical point and/or local maximum of $g(u,v)=6u^2v+2v^3-45u-51v+7$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

> Determine whether $B\!\equiv\!\left(\dfrac32,\dfrac52\right)$ is a critical point and/or local maximum of the function $g(u,v)=6u^2v+2v^3-45u-51v+7$

a) Is $B$ a critical point?
b) Is $B$ a local maximum point ?

**Update:**
here’s my attempt at a)

$g’_u=12uv-45\\$

$g’_v=6u^{2}+6v^{2}-51$

$g’_u(B)=12\!\cdot\!\dfrac{3}{2}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{5}{2}-45=\dfrac{12\!\cdot\!15}{4}-45=45-45=0\\$

$g’_v(B)=6\!\cdot\!\dfrac{9}{4}+6\!\cdot\!\dfrac{25}{4}-51=\dfrac{54+150}{4}-51=51-51=0$

And this means that $B$ is a critical point right?
And is everthing correct up to this point?

Comment: And what have you tried? Hint: first derivatives.

Comment: yeah i sort of tried that but i have no idea how to them, i've gotten different results and don't know which are correct and then for the second derivatives to be able to get my hessian matrix, i have no idea how to do the f''(uv)

Comment: We can't tell you which are correct without you showing your try. Edit your original post to include your attempts. I suggest reading the MathJax tutorial too; https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: ok thank you, i will try a few more times and edit the post, the problem is im really new at these and have no idea what im doing

Comment: @Badger: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please always include the work you've done, even if it's incorrect. This will help people avoid wasting time (theirs and yours) explaining things you already understand. Moreover, it may be easier for someone to spot an error in your attempt, or to nudge you to the correct result, than to work through the problem from scratch. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Badger, if you want us to help you, you should edit your original post to include your attempts and more context, otherwise moderators will close your question very soon.

Comment: @Badger, click on [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn to ask a good question, otherwise moderators will close your post.

Comment: @Badger, yes, you are right, it means that $B$ is a critical point and it is everything correct so far.

Comment: @Badger, $B$ is a local minimum point.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen im sorry i'm not sure I fully understand the question since im not studying in english but all i basically know is that the critical point in most cases is when f'(x)=0 and f'(y)=0, and i barely know how to use the hasseian matrix, and i think i have to use it for the second part of the problem

Comment: Thank you @Angelo

Comment: @Badger, I have already answered the question b). If you like my answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark (near my answer) in order to turn it green. You can also upvote me if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second derivatives of the function $\,g(u,v)\,$ are :

$g’’_{uu}=12v$

$g’’_{uv}=g’’_{vu}=12u$

$g’’_{vv}=12v$

The Hessian matrix is :

$H(u,v)=\begin{vmatrix}g’’_{uu} &g’’_{uv}\\g’’_{vu} &g’’_{vv}\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}12v &12u\\12u &12v\end{vmatrix}=144\left(v^2-u^2\right).$

Moreover ,

$g’’_{uu}(B)=12\!\cdot\!\dfrac52=30>0\;\;,$

$H(B)=144\left(\dfrac{25}4-\dfrac94\right)=144\cdot\dfrac{16}4=576>0\;.$

Since $\;g’’_{uu}(B)>0\;$ and $\;H(B)>0\;,\;$ then $\,B\,$ is a local minimum point.

Comment: thank you so much, i was actually on the right path to solve it :)